# Using of google-api-translate-java in my Java web based project

Tags: java, google-translate

I used google-api-translate-java in my web based application to translate some text extracted from an image. my code is as follows

```
package translators;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.google.translate.api.v2.core.Translator;
import org.google.translate.api.v2.core.TranslatorException;
import org.google.translate.api.v2.core.model.Detection;
import org.google.translate.api.v2.core.model.Language;
import org.google.translate.api.v2.core.model.Translation;

/**
 *
 * @author User
 */
public class Translators {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    private static Translator translator;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {

        if (args.length != 1) {

            System.out.println("Google API key must be passed as the first and last argument");

            System.exit(1);

        }
        translator = new Translator(args[0]);

        try {

            testLanguages();

            testTranslate();

            testDetect();

        } catch (TranslatorException e) {

            System.out.println("Google Translate API returned an error " + e.getMessage());

            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {

            translator.close();

        }

    }

    public static void testLanguages() throws IOException, URISyntaxException, TranslatorException {

        Language[] languages = translator.languages("en"); 

        System.out.println("languages = " + Arrays.toString(languages));
    }

    public static void testTranslate() throws IOException, URISyntaxException, TranslatorException {


        Translation fromEnglish = translator.translate("I", "en", "es");

        System.out.println("'I' in en = '" + fromEnglish.getTranslatedText() + "' in es");


        Translation fromUnknown = translator.translate("I", null, "es");

        System.out.println("'I' in " + fromUnknown.getDetectedSourceLanguage() + " = '" + fromUnknown.getTranslatedText() + "' in es");


        String[] sourceTexts = {"I", "a"};

        Translation[] translations = translator.translate(sourceTexts, null, "es");

        for (int i = 0, sourceTextsLength = sourceTexts.length; i < sourceTextsLength; i++) {

            System.out.println("'" + sourceTexts[i] + "' in en = " + "'" + translations[i].getTranslatedText() + "' in es");

        }


    }

    private static void testDetect() throws IOException, URISyntaxException, TranslatorException {

        Detection[][] detections = translator.detect(new String[]{"I", "We"});

        System.out.println("detections = " + Arrays.deepToString(detections));


    }
}
```

I imported the required jar file to the libraries also. But I get the following output

```
run:
Google API key must be passed as the first and last argument
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

I can't figure out the reason. Does anybody know the reason for this?Thank you in advance.

**UPDATED**

I replaced the command line argument part by the following two lines

```
String key = "AIzaSyAbofnwFYErbdycq5E8ip7f3_8mT6T_Tjc";

        translator = new Translator(key);
```

Then I got the following output

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
languages = [Afrikaans, Albanian, Amharic, Arabic, Armenian, Azerbaijani, Basque, Belarusian, Bengali, Bosnian, Bulgarian, Catalan, Cebuano, Chichewa, Chinese (Simplified), Chinese (Traditional), Corsican, Croatian, Czech, Danish, Dutch, English, Esperanto, Estonian, Filipino, Finnish, French, Frisian, Galician, Georgian, German, Greek, Gujarati, Haitian Creole, Hausa, Hawaiian, Hebrew, Hindi, Hmong, Hungarian, Icelandic, Igbo, Indonesian, Irish, Italian, Japanese, Javanese, Kannada, Kazakh, Khmer, Korean, Kurdish (Kurmanji), Kyrgyz, Lao, Latin, Latvian, Lithuanian, Luxembourgish, Macedonian, Malagasy, Malay, Malayalam, Maltese, Maori, Marathi, Mongolian, Myanmar (Burmese), Nepali, Norwegian, Pashto, Persian, Polish, Portuguese, Punjabi, Romanian, Russian, Samoan, Scots Gaelic, Serbian, Sesotho, Shona, Sindhi, Sinhala, Slovak, Slovenian, Somali, Spanish, Sundanese, Swahili, Swedish, Tajik, Tamil, Telugu, Thai, Turkish, Ukrainian, Urdu, Uzbek, Vietnamese, Welsh, Xhosa, Yiddish, Yoruba, Zulu]
org.google.translate.api.v2.core.TranslatorException: ApiError{code=403, message='Daily Limit Exceeded', errors=[ErrorEntry{domain='usageLimits', reason='dailyLimitExceeded', message='Daily Limit Exceeded', location='null', locationType='null'}]}
Google Translate API returned an error ApiError{code=403, message='Daily Limit Exceeded', errors=[ErrorEntry{domain='usageLimits', reason='dailyLimitExceeded', message='Daily Limit Exceeded', location='null', locationType='null'}]}
    at org.google.translate.api.v2.core.Translator.readResponse(Translator.java:279)    at org.google.translate.api.v2.core.Translator.readResponse(Translator.java:279)
    at org.google.translate.api.v2.core.Translator.translate(Translator.java:124)
    at org.google.translate.api.v2.core.Translator.translate(Translator.java:87)
    at translators.Translators.testTranslate(Translators.java:73)
    at translators.Translators.main(Translators.java:45)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)
```

Do you know the exact reason? Can't I use this API for free?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this region of code:-

```
 if (args.length != 1) {

        System.out.println("Google API key must be passed as the first and last argument");

        System.exit(1);

    }
    translator = new Translator(args[0]);
```

which means you have to pass a command line argument, which happens to be the google API key. You can remove this check and then put a hard coded key in place of args[0] is you like to test it but I would suggest just pass it as a command line argument.

Comment: I have updated the question as you mentioned. Can you please check it and help me?

Comment: It depends on how frequently you use your API. Is there any rate limit you saw when you signed up (for example 20 calls per minute?). Moreover is this occurring in the first trial?